# Is there an official detailed documentation of the possible nodes,values and attributes than can be found in system.xml?

Tags: magento2, system.xml

Is there an official detailed documentation of the possible nodes,values and attributes than can be found in system.xml

I can figure out the meaning of some of them myself, but some of them elude me.

For example why do sections of groups have a **type** attribute, what else could they be other than **text**. Mind you that section and groups are not inputs.

What does the **canRestore="1"** attribute in fields mean?

Who is responsible for interpreting the system.xml information and transforming it into a form?

To get a feeling of what I'm looking please take a look at this documentation of the layout instructions [Layout instructions docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the world of Magento development.  A lot is not documented and basically you have to educate yourself with trial and error working towards an answer.

There is no public documentation.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/0eb8677b0b4e35606032e856cc1ef7c80e68829f/app/code/Magento/Config/Model/Config/Structure/Element/Field.php#L295-L298

```
    /**
     * Check if the field can be restored to default
     *
     * @return bool
     * @since 100.1.0
     */
    public function canRestore()
    {
        return isset($this->_data['canRestore']) && (int)$this->_data['canRestore'];
    }
```

Which is not clear at all.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2bca2aa1a6c1828c379bb9c75db2810a92cd3d37/app/code/Magento/Config/Block/System/Config/Form.php#L380

`'can_restore_to_default' => $this->isCanRestoreToDefault($field->canRestore()),`

https://github.com/magento/magento2/search?q=can_restore_to_default&unscoped_q=can_restore_to_default

No results

https://github.com/magento/magento2/search?q=RestoreToDefault&unscoped_q=RestoreToDefault

More meaningful results

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/0eb8677b0b4e35606032e856cc1ef7c80e68829f/app/code/Magento/Backend/view/adminhtml/web/template/form/element/helper/fallback-reset-link.html

```html
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<button class="action-tertiary"
        click="element.restoreToDefault">
    <span translate="'Use Default Value'"></span>
</button>
```

So it means these config options have the 'Use Default Value' option

Comment: Thx for that. I'll leave the question open maybe someone finds a detailed list.